# PHP how remove array from multidimensional array and create new array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
array(3) { 
["cod"]=> array(3) { 
    ["code"]=> string(3) "cod" 
    ["title"]=> string(38) "Pay on delivery" 
    ["sort_order"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
["pp_standard"]=> array(3) { 
    ["code"]=> string(11) "pp_standard" 
    ["title"]=> string(6) "PayPal" 
    ["sort_order"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 

["bank_transfer"]=> array(3) { 
    ["code"]=> string(13) "bank_transfer" 
    ["title"]=> string(25) "bank_transfer" 
    ["sort_order"]=> string(1) "2" 
    } 
}
```

How I can remove full array

```
["cod"]=> array(3) {     
    ["code"]=> string(3) "cod" 
    ["title"]=> string(38) "Pay on delivery" 
    ["sort_order"]=> string(1) "1" 
    }
```

from the multidimensional array above and create new multidimensional array without ["cod"] array?
Thanks

Comment: try using `array_splice`.

Comment: King King how would that work?

Comment: normally `array_splice` is used to remove (and also replace but this is optional) elements (normally range of elements) in an array. Try searching for its documentation and you'll understand its usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unset($arr['cod']);` is all you need. Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php